# The same ipv6 prefix of router and PC, how does the ISP's router send the package to my PC?

Tags: networking, dhcp, ipv6

There is a ipv6 address whose prefix length is 64 on my router. The DHCPv6 mode of router is hybrid. The ipv6 prefix length length is 64 too on my PC under the router.

```
router     eth0    2001:2:3:4:2eb2:1aff:feff:b19d/64
(OpenWrt)          fe80::2eb2:1aff:feff:b19d/64 scope link

           br-lan  2001:2:3:4:2eb2:1aff:feff:b19d/64 scope global noprefixroute dynamic
                   fe80::2eb2:1aff:feff:b1a0/64 scope link
                   fdf8:18ec:159f::1/64 scope global noprefixroute

PC(Win10)  WLAN    2001:2:3:4:9555:e337:8400:b840
        link-local fe80::9555:e337:8400:b840%13
   Default Gateway fe80::2eb2:1aff:feff:b1a0%13
```

I known that the ipv4 package forward is based on the route table, which depend on the CIDR and the different prefix length of ipv4 to identify different subnet.

I also know that the ipv4 can use NAT (Net address Transform) to send package to my router and it do NAT and then send the package to my PC.

But for ipv6, the prefix length of ipv6 is the same on both my router and PC, and there is no NAT in package forwarding, I also didn't do any configure expect switching the ipv6 mode to hybrid.

> So my router and PC both have an address in the same network as said by [@Sander Steffann](https://superuser.com/users/93929/sander-steffann)

How does the ISP's router knows that send the package whose destination is my PC to my router?

**edit**: update the address assigned to each interface.

The LuCI of my router show that there is no address distributed by my router. The follow is the content of `/etc/config/dhcp`.

```
config dhcp 'wan6'
        option interface 'wan'
        option ra 'relay'
        option ndp 'relay'
        option dhcpv6 'relay'
        option master '1'
        option start '100'
        option limit '150'
        option leasetime '12h'
```

For the `relay` in the dhcp config file and the blank table of dhcpv6 distribute address, and thanks to [@Sander Steffann](https://superuser.com/users/93929/sander-steffann) I think that all the address is distributed by ISP's gateway.

I heard about that there is a protocol called NDP (Neighbor Discovery Protocol) and there is a `option ndp relay` entry. So **does the ISP know all my devices' ipv6 addresses and it's link-local address**? Corresponding to all of my devices, **are there much many route rules at the ISP's gateway**?

Besides, **is it possible to map multi ipv6 address to a single link-local address**? **Is it ok to hold so much many rules on a single ISP's gateway**.

I am sorry that I wrote too much and I bold my questions.

Comment: Could you clarify in your post _which interface_ on the router is the address assigned to? And update the list with addresses assigned to other interfaces as well. (A router that belongs only to a single network isn't much of a router.)

Comment: I am sorry that I edit my question for too long time, I thought much and updated the question, Thanks for your patience and help.

Comment: I see -- using "relay" mode makes the situation somewhat different from usual. It means your router is not creating its own subnet, but acting more like a transparent bridge than a router. (Is there a reason you've chosen this mode though?)

Comment: Thanks for your explaination. The reason I use "relay" just because many blog said it works. But now I think I need to try dhcpv6 in future days. Thanks again for your patience.

Answer (score 2):

The prefix size determines the size of the network (so all devices together), not how many addresses belong to a specific device.

So your router and PC both have an address in the same network. This is what you want.

The ISP has some mechanism of knowing that that /64 is connected to your router, so when it needs to send a packet to an address in the /64 it will send it to your router. Your router then sees that the destination address is on a directly connected network, and it will forward the packet to your PC.

Outbound traffic works the same: your PC knows that your router has routes to the rest of the world (it's the PC's default gateway) so it sends its packets there. The router then has a default route to the ISP, which is the router's default gateway, and forwards the packet there.

Comment: So, are all of my devices (my PC and router) in the same subnet/64 which hosted by ISP? And there is a huge ipv6 route table in my router's gateway (ISP's router) saving many entries like ```a:b:c:d:m:n:o:p via a:b:c:d:w:x:y:z```?

Comment: @Leafee: No, the ISP's route table only needs a single route for the entire /64 prefix. That's literally the point of subnets and prefixes. But you still haven't answered my question about your router's addresses (whether you're seeing :m:n:o:p on the "LAN" side or on the "WAN" side), and I feel like you're missing an important part that the LAN /64 does not extend all the way to your ISP -- the boundary is at _your_ router.

Comment: If there is no route rule in ISP's gateway, how does it determine to send the package whose destination is PC to router? Or is there a mechanism like `arp` in ipv4 to map the ipv6 global address to a link-local address?